# How to have different sets of data for each CollectionView section?

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView with multiple section, and I need the sections to be dynamic (meaning it can have more or less amount).

The problem I am having is that I do not want to use a new array for each set of data with a custom model, but instead to have it all in one array. And this creates a problem because I would not know which data for which section.

Here is how my firebase data looks like

```
- kZ1cL9GWHpOdvW0Bn9zl4jkIkzc2 (CollectionView Section)
         - ArrayID
             -dvW0Bn9zl4jkIkzc2 (Data in section)
             -j29dn10Dnso291xc2 (Data in section)

- sk2cL9GWHpj209Uie4n9zlfj21fsDs (CollectionView Section)
         - ArrayID
             -zl4sn9zl4jkIkzc2am (Data in section)
             -o291xdn10Dnso291x9 (Data in section)
```

Now I know how to read firebase data and all that I just can't seem to figure out how to put those data in the right CollectionView section.

**So My Question Is:**
How can I get those data to know which CollectionView section they are suppose to be in, using a single array?

Comment: You can have an array of arrays, and in the number of sections you say that the amount of sections is equal to the amount of arrays, and in the number of rows, you use `arrays[indexPath.section].count`

Comment: You can use `filter()` to filter the array for each section on some property.

Comment: @SavcaMarin How do i have arrays of arrays of a custom model?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, just in case anyone needs it.

You could initialize the array of arrays of a custom models like this

```
var arrayOfArrays = [[CustomModel]]()
```

then you are able to just add sections like

```
arrayOfArrays = [[CustomModel], [CustomModel]]
```